# symfony 3.4 form insert to database error500

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

I have problem with symfony 3.4... it should pretty simple but... The thing is that when i trying to create simple form and insert data to mysql database AFTER SUBMIT i get error500. Project is already at LIVE server, not localy, so i can`t automatically generate route to function with composer, i wrote it manually. Form renders fine. Mysql fields is id- int(11) AI and title- varchar(255).

**My Form class:**

```
use AppBundle\Entity\IndexAdvantage;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class IndexAdvantageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Title'])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\IndexAdvantage'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_index_advantage';
    }
}
```

**My Entity:** *AppBundle\Entity\IndexAdvantage.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="index_advantage")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\IndexAdvantageRepository")
 */
class IndexAdvantage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**My controller** AppBundle\Controller\Admin\IndexController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use AppBundle\Controller\AbstractBaseController;
use AppBundle\Form\IndexAdvantageType;
use AppBundle\Entity\IndexAdvantage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


class AdminIndexController extends AbstractBaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/")
     */
    public function IndexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AppBundle:AdminIndex:index.html.twig', array());
    }
...<<<<SOME OTHER FUNCTIONS>>>>>>>.....
    /**
     * @Route(
     *      "/advantage/new",
     *      name="admin.index_advantage.new",
     *      methods={"GET", "POST"}
     * )
     */
    public function newAdvantageAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $advantage = new IndexAdvantage();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\IndexAdvantageType', $advantage);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $advantage = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($advantage);
            $em->flush($advantage);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:AdminIndexAdvantage:new.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }
}
```

**My form twig** *AppBundle\Resources\view\AdminIndexAdvantage\new.html.twig*

```
{% extends 'adminLayout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>NEW</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I also manually created route to function `newAdvantageAction` at `var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php` and `var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php`

```
        'admin.index_advantage.new' => array (0 => array (0 => 'id',),
  1 => array ('_controller' =>'AppBundle\\Controller\\Admin\\AdminIndexController::newAdvantageAction',),
  2 => array (  ),
  3 => array (0 => array (0 => 'text', 1 => '/advantage/new',), 1 =>array (0 => 'variable', 1 => '/', 2 => '[^/]++', 3 => 'id',), 2 => array ( 0 => 'text', 1 => '/admin/index',),), 4 => array (  ), 5 => array (  ),),
```

and

```
                // admin_index_advantage_new
                if (0 === strpos($pathinfo, '/admin/index') && preg_match('#^/admin/index/(?P<id>[^/]++)/advantage/new$#sD', $pathinfo, $matches)) {
                    $ret = $this->mergeDefaults(array_replace($matches, ['_route' => 'admin.index_advantage.new']), array (  '_controller' => 'AppBundle\\Controller\\Admin\\AdminIndexController::newAdvantageAction',));
                    if (!in_array($canonicalMethod, ['GET', 'POST'])) {
                        $allow = array_merge($allow, ['GET', 'POST']);
                        goto not_adminindex_advantagenew;
                    }

                    return $ret;
                }
                not_adminindex_advantagenew:
```

Comment: "Project is already at LIVE server, not localy, so i can`t automatically generate route to function with composer, i wrote it manually." I don't understand why you would go modifying the cache files manually instead of writing the actual route definition into the project? Additionally the error logs should contain more info what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: # config/routes.yaml
```blog_list:
    path: /blog

    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::list```   ------- for example route definition somethig like that ? And error log at browser console shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()     new:1`

Comment: yes, that would be one of the normal ways how to define it. The logs refer to the server side logs of the project where you can see what is causing the 500 error (assuming that you don't have error logging explicitly disabled for your project).

Answer (score 0):

I added route admin_index_advantage_new:

```
#app/config/routng.yaml

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

admin_index_advantage_new:
  path: /advantage/new
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AdminIndexAdvantage:new }
```

it should execute:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use AppBundle\Controller\AbstractBaseController;
use AppBundle\Entity\IndexAdvantage;
use AppBundle\Entity\Laboratory;
use AppBundle\Form\IndexAdvantageType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class AdminIndexAdvantageController extends AbstractBaseController
{

    public function newAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AppBundle:AdminIndexAdvantage:new.html.twig');
    }

}
```

and go to domain.com/advantage/new and i get '404 page not found' :/